# What does this symbol make inside htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

frequently I use this:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ m#^.*TTT.*$#i">
```

I would like to know what is =~? I suppose it's related to "equal". So how do I make "different"?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation of apache's rewriting module. It is of excellent quality, comes with great examples and answers your questions.

Comment: `=~` is for regex evaluation. [Check this official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html)

Comment: @anubhava thanks! And what is the negation of =~ ? I want to negate e regex. If you can post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=~` is used for regular expression based evaluation in expressions. [Here is official Apache documentation for expressions.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html)

To negate use `!~` like this:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} !~ /foobar/">
   Redirect 301 "/" "http://www.example.com/"
</If>
```

[Check Binary Operators List](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html#binop)

#### Comparison operators

```
Name    Description
==      String equality
!=      String inequality
<       String less than
<=      String less than or equal
>       String greater than
>=      String greater than or equal
=~       String matches the regular expression
!~       String does not match the regular expression
-eq eq  Integer equality
-ne ne  Integer inequality
-lt lt  Integer less than
-le le  Integer less than or equal
-gt gt  Integer greater than
-ge ge  Integer greater than or equal
```

Comment: Didnt work! I found that I need to replace =~ with =! and it worked perfectly. Anyway I will accept your answer.

Comment: Ah that's right. It is fixed here and thanks for accepting.

Comment: @anubhava - I came across your post in an attempt to resolve an issue (https://superuser.com/questions/1471158/htaccess-if-directive-does-not-work) I'm facing.Would you be able to shed light on it?